# php - storing checkbox value in db and read them

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, checkbox

I have a list of services stored in the database that users need to check. The list gets updated regularly.
They are stored in table "services" like so:

```
|id|service|
| 1|foo    |
| 2|bar    |
```

When user check the checkboxes, i store the ID values in the "services" cell from "people" table.

```
$services = mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',', $_POST['services']));
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE people SET services='$services' WHERE id='$id'") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

Till here everything works fine.

Now, i want to list all my services from table "services" and cross-check with the services from user cell "services", and the one in user cell.

The final echo should look like this.

```
<label>$service</label>
<input name="services[]" type="checkbox" id="services[]" value="$id" $checked>
```

Can someone help me with this one?
Thank you!

P.S: i tried to make it after this http://corpocrat.com/2009/05/24/how-to-store-and-retreive-checkbox-value-in-mysql-with-php/ but i couldn't echo the labels and then i screw it all up

Comment: Side note: You'll probably find data a lot easier to manipulate and display if you store elements distinctly rather than as a delimited list in a single field.  For a setup like this you'd want three tables.  People, Services, and PeopleServices (which is just foreign keys to the id of People and the id of Services).

Comment: You DB input structure is quite silly. You should create different columns for each checkbox's value with a TRUE (1) or FALSE (0) value. It would make your life much more easier..

Comment: @Nav Can  you be more specific?

Comment: Nav - Can  you be more specific?
I have a table with services, a table with people. Each people can check different services (say 4/9). I tought a cell with services id delimited should be enough. If you have a better soultion, please give it to me...not just say i am wrong.

@David you seem right. I first wanted to make it with three tables, but then i choose to make it with too. Please tell me how to loop them in your way, making the inputs checked if a user haves them and i will do it your way. :D Thx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I could get your mean or not. I hope I could. Otherwise, comment this post ...

You'd better to create a better database structure.

```
tbl_users                  tbl_services                tbl_assign
+-------------+            +-------------+             +----------------+
| uid | name  |            | sid | title |             | id | uid | sid |
+-------------+            +-------------+             +----------------+
|     |       |            |     |       |             |    |     |     |
+-------------+            +-------------+             +----------------+
```

In this structure, you can specify one or more service to each user.
Now, you need to insert or delete records in/from tbl_assign to grant or revoke services to each user.

I hope you can do it.

Comment: Thank you. My problem is the cross checking. How to see if user have this service checked when the user later edit this? 

I want to return all the services, but the chosen one to be checked.
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I finaly made it. 
Maybe this is not the best answer to my problem, but is better than nothing.

```
$servicii_user = mysql_query("SELECT servicii FROM people WHERE id='$id'")
or die(mysql_error());  
$ss = mysql_fetch_array($servicii_user);
$servicii_selectate = array();
$servicii_selectate= explode(',',$ss['servicii']);



$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM servicii")
or die(mysql_error());  

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if(in_array($row[0], $servicii_selectate)){
        echo '<input name="servicii[]" type="checkbox" value="'.$row[0].'" CHECKED>'.$row[1].' ';
    }else{
        echo '<input name="servicii[]" type="checkbox" value="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[1].' ';
    }
}
```